# How to get current extension delegate on watchOS?

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

Is there a way to get the instance of extension delegate on watchOS? For example, can I get its instance from an interface controller or other code in the watch extension?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
[WKExtension sharedExtension].delegate
```

Answer (score 25):

In Swift:

```
let watchDelegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as? ExtensionDelegate
```

Comment: The sharedExtension() function has been renamed, so the statement is now
`let watchDelegate = WKExtension.shared().delegate as? ExtensionDelegate`